# $ionicModal returns undefined error?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a modal on click, I've tried the code earlier and it was working, now trying it in new project and getting this error:

```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined at
> Scope.$scope.openModal (controllers.js:64) at fn (eval at compile
> (ionic.bundle.js:27615), :4:288) at ionic.bundle.js:65290 at
> Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:30372) at Scope.$apply
> (ionic.bundle.js:30472) at HTMLDivElement. (ionic.bundle.js:65289) at
> defaultHandlerWrapper (ionic.bundle.js:16764) at
> HTMLDivElement.eventHandler (ionic.bundle.js:16752) at
> triggerMouseEvent (ionic.bundle.js:2953) at tapClick
> (ionic.bundle.js:2942)
```

here is the code:

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modal.html', function($ionicModal) {
$scope.modal = $ionicModal;
}, {
scope: $scope,
animation: 'slide-in-up'
});

$scope.openModal = function(scode) {

$scope.mcode = scode;

 $scope.modal.show();
}
```

this is modal view, as the error says its not Getting path to the URL in the project : please see the code for modal

```
<script id="templates/modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-modal-view>
        <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-dark">
          <h1 class="title">Details</h1>
          <button class="button button-clear button-primary" ng-click="modal.hide()">Cancel</button>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content class="padding">
          <div class="modal">

<div style="font-size:3.2vw" ng-repeat="title in scode.Legs | filter:selectedId"  >

     <span ng-repeat="charge in scode.Itineraries | filter: selectedId "  >

      <div class="list card" style="padding:5vw" ng-repeat="data1 in charge.PricingOptions ">


              <span ng-repeat="bong in data1.Agents">
              <span ng-repeat="scode in scode.Agents | filter: bong">  
              <i>{{scode.Name}}</i>
              </span>
              </span>

          <a class="button button-outline button-positive"  style="padding-bottom:4vw;font-size:3vw;position:absolute;right:5px;line-height: 10vw !important;
    min-height: 10vw !important;" ng-click="openCordovaWebView(data1.DeeplinkUrl)">{{scode.Currencies[0].Symbol}}{{data1.Price}}</a>


            </div>


        </span>

 </div>
        </span>
</div>

</div>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-modal-view>
    </script>
```

Comment: where did you put the script template?

Comment: After </ion-content> and before </ion-view>

Comment: try change the id to `/templates/modal.html`, also change the first parameter of fromTemplateUrl to `/templates/modal.htm`,  sometimes angular may find the wrong file place with a relative path

Comment: Tried it ! No luck. Still the same error

Comment: hmm, that is very strange, you could try to put the template in a separate file without script tag,

Comment: Thanks Marko , it's working that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

calling `$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl` would return a promise which resolving with a modal instance:

```
   $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modal.html', {
       scope: $scope,
       animation: 'slide-in-up'
   }).then(function(modal){
       $scope.modal = modal;
   }, function(reason){
       console.log(reason);
   })
```

Comment: make sure the modal initialized successfully, you could log the error in rejected handler

Comment: 'Object {data: "Cannot GET /templates/modal.html↵", status: 404, config: Object, statusText: "Not Found"}
config
:
Object
data
:
"Cannot GET /templates/modal.html↵"
headers
:
(name)
status
:
404
statusText
:
"Not Found"
__proto__
:
Object'


the response i am getting , is there any problem with modal view>?

Comment: which means the modal could not find the template at location `templates/modal.html`, if you are using `webpack`, make sure the output bundle file contains the correct path to the templates folder, or you could use `ngtemplate-loader` to include the templates into bundle

Comment: hi Marko, ive updated question with the modal , please help , the same code was working on other project , what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

See how `$scope.openModal` and `$scope.closeModal` and responsible for opening and closing modal below.

**View:**

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-content>
     <button ng-click="openModal()">Open modal</button>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>

<script id="my-modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-modal-view>
    <ion-header-bar>
      <h1 class="title">My Modal title</h1>
      <button ng-click="closeModal()">Close Modal</button>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      Hello!
    </ion-content>
  </ion-modal-view>
</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
angular.module('testApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('MyController', function($scope, $ionicModal) {
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('my-modal.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });

  //shows modal
  $scope.openModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
  };

  // hides modal, not destroy
  $scope.closeModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };
});
```